# UDP packet sent by Ostinato not being received over raw socket. Wireshark captures it though

Tags: sockets, udp, wireshark, packet, packet-capture

I have written this simple code to received packets with IP & UDP header using RAW sockets. It works fine with my test app which sends UDP packets over RAW sockets. Now I test my code with pcap files. I used Ostineto utility and created a simple IP/UDP packet. I'm sending it over eth1 in my case. Source and dest MAC as well as IP address is the same in this packet. Wireshark can capture this and everything looks fine. But my RAW socket never receives. This is really blocking my further development. Please help.

BTW, I'm testing this on Ubuntu 12.04.

Here is my code

```
int main(void)
{
    int s, bytesrecvd;
    struct sockaddr_in saddr;
    char packet[100];
    char *payload;

    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0) {
    perror("error:");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    memset(packet, 0, sizeof(packet));
    int fromlen = sizeof(saddr);

    while(1) {
        bytesrecvd = recvfrom(s, (char *)&packet, sizeof(packet), 0,
                             (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, (socklen_t *)&fromlen);
        if(bytesrecvd < 0) {
            perror("packet receive error:");
        }
        printf("bytes received %d\n",bytesrecvd);

        parse_ip_header(packet, bytesrecvd);
        parse_udp_header(packet, bytesrecvd);

        payload = packet + sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof (struct udphdr);
        printf("payload: %s\n", payload);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Stackoverflow didn't allow me to post images, otherwise I was going to share screenshot of ostinato with packet contents for review.

Here is text of pcap

```
Frame 1: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits)
WTAP_ENCAP: 1
Arrival Time: Dec 31, 1969 18:00:00.000000000 CST
[Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
Epoch Time: 0.000000000 seconds
[Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
[Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
[Time since reference or first frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
Frame Number: 1
Frame Length: 60 bytes (480 bits)
Capture Length: 60 bytes (480 bits)
[Frame is marked: False]
[Frame is ignored: False]
[Protocols in frame: eth:ip:udp:data]
Ethernet II, Src: HewlettP_72:2e:08 (ac:16:2d:72:2e:08), Dst: HewlettP_72:2e:08     (ac:16:2d:72:2e:08)
Destination: HewlettP_72:2e:08 (ac:16:2d:72:2e:08)
    Address: HewlettP_72:2e:08 (ac:16:2d:72:2e:08)
    .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
    .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
Source: HewlettP_72:2e:08 (ac:16:2d:72:2e:08)
    Address: HewlettP_72:2e:08 (ac:16:2d:72:2e:08)
    .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
    .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
Type: IP (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.1.15.47 (10.1.15.47), Dst: 10.1.15.47 (10.1.15.47)
Version: 4
Header length: 20 bytes
Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-  Capable Transport))
    0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0x00)
    .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport)   (0x00)
Total Length: 46
Identification: 0x04d2 (1234)
Flags: 0x00
    0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
    .0.. .... = Don't fragment: Not set
    ..0. .... = More fragments: Not set
Fragment offset: 0
Time to live: 127
Protocol: UDP (17)
Header checksum: 0x048e [correct]
    [Good: True]
    [Bad: False]
Source: 10.1.15.47 (10.1.15.47)
Destination: 10.1.15.47 (10.1.15.47)
```

User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 0 (0), Dst Port: 0 (0)
    Source port: 0 (0)
    Destination port: 0 (0)
    Length: 26
    Checksum: 0x0000 (none)
        [Good Checksum: False]